# Largest possible value of a sum

Tags: linear-algebra, summation, integer-lattices

This question has been confusing me and I would love some help.

If $M$ is $n$ by $n$, symmetric, [positive definite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix) and integer valued and $n$ is a fixed positive integer, what is the large possible value of

$$\sum_{x \in \mathbb{Z}^n}e^{-\pi^2 {\bf x}^T M^{-1}{\bf x}}\;?$$

Comment: Where did this sum come from? On this site you should state the motivation behind your questions and what you've tried, as the FAQ says.

Comment: @Crostul Yes. I think that is part of positive definite.

Comment: Take $M=\sigma I$. Then with increasing $\sigma$ the sum is growing to infinity.

Comment: It should be related to $\sqrt{\det(M/\pi)}$

Comment: @robjohn That would be very interesting.

Comment: @YvesDaoust For a fixed $n$, what does $M = \sigma I$ give you and is that the largest possible for that value of $n$?

Comment: Obviously infinity, for any $n$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Oh that's confusing.  The sum comes from http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1699259/72724  and I thought that that sum converged if $M$ was positive definite. What have I got wrong?

Comment: You didn't ask the right question. That sum must be divided by $\sqrt{\det M}$ to ensure a finite value.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Thank you. I will ask another question having accepted the answer here.

Comment: $$ \begin{align} \sum_{x\in\mathbb{Z}^n}e^{-\pi^2x^T M^{-1}x} &\sim\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}e^{-\pi^2x^T M^{-1}x}\,\mathrm{d}x\\ &=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}e^{-\pi x^2}\sqrt{\det\left(\frac M\pi\right)}\,\,\mathrm{d}x\\ &=\sqrt{\det\left(\frac M\pi\right)} \end{align} $$

Comment: @robjohn Thank you but I worry that this approximation might not be good in high dimensions. Take the original LHS sum in the linked question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1699078/a-query-about-poisson-summation-and-matrices9 . We could also approximate that by an integral but would it be a good approximation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For all positive integers $p \ge 1$ consider the matrix $pI$. Then
$$\mathbf{x}^T (pI)^{-1}\mathbf{x} = \frac{1}{p} ||\mathbf{x}||^2$$

With a little of algebra one can see that
$$e^{- \pi^2\mathbf{x}^T (pI)^{-1}\mathbf{x}} \ge \frac{1}{2}$$
is equivalent to
$$||\mathbf{x}|| \le \frac{\sqrt{ \log 2}}{\pi} \sqrt{p}$$

so that taking arbitrarily large $p$ you have an arbitrarily large amount of summands $\ge 1/2$, letting your sum blow up to $\infty$. In particular, a maximum value for that sum cannot be achieved.

Comment: Thank you. If the values in $M$ are bounded by $n$ in absolute value, what do you get as the upper bound?

Comment: @Anush I totally have no answer to that.

Comment: Thank you. I will ask another question.